# C# : How to resize image proportionately with max height

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-resizing, aspect-ratio

I need to resize my image proportionately without changing aspect ratio.I have the code to resize with fixed hight and width but I need to resize image proportionately with max height(say 600 pixels). How can I modify the code to suit my requirement?

```
public static void Main()
{
  var image = Image.FromFile(@"c:\logo.png");
  var newImage = ScaleImage(image, 300, 400);
  newImage.Save(@"c:\test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}

public static Image ScaleImage(Image image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
 {
  var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
  var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
  var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

  var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
  var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

  var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
  Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
  return newImage;
}
```

Please provide your valuable thoughts.

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Comment: with all due respect , kindly go through my requirement. This code uses max height and max width whereas as I need to proportionately change the image dimension keeping the height alone to a maximum number (say 600).

Comment: I don't know what the problem is but if I'm not mistaken, your code does resize the image without changing the aspect ratio. Can you add an example of what you expect to happen?

Comment: use ratioY instead of ratio, for calculating the newWidth and newHeigth

Comment: @remko: Yes you are absolutely right, but in my code I pass a fixed height ans width to the ScaleImage method. What I actually need is to pass the dimension with a fixed height but a proportionate width. IS it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This almost feels to easy and I feel I'm missing something. Anyway, won't that do the trick?

```
public static Image ScaleImage(Image image, int maxHeight) 
{ 
    var ratio = (double)maxHeight / image.Height; 

    var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio); 
    var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio); 

    var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight); 
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    {
        g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight); 
    }
    return newImage; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try it out.

Comment: What I need to add to prevent scaling an image that i fits within the max height or max width, and it one of the sides is larger, just reduce the size until it fits the needed area while keeping porpotions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following function

```
public Bitmap ProportionallyResizeBitmapByHeight(Bitmap imgToResize, int height)
{
  int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
  int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

  float scale = 0;

  scale = (height / (float)sourceHeight);

  int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * scale);
  int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * scale);

  Bitmap result = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
  result.SetResolution(imgToResize.HorizontalResolution, imgToResize.VerticalResolution);
  Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result);
  g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
  g.Dispose();

  return result;
}
```

Comment: @Imran Thanks a lot. Let me try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Well, thinking through the process: 
if you have an image that 800 x 600 in size and want to resize it to newWidth x 400 height (plus whatever the respective newWidth will be), you get the ratio by dividing the newHeight (maxHeight in your case) with 600 and multiply 800 with this ratio, right?

So, in this case you need to change maxWidth and maxHeight to optional parameters (say 800 by 600) to give yourself some dynamism and get the following:

```
public static Image ScaleImage(Image image, int maxWidth = 800, int maxHeight = 600)
 {

  int newWidth;
  int newHeight;
  double ratio = image.Height / image.Width;

  if(maxHeight != 600) {

     newWidth = image.Width * ratio;
     newHeight = maxHeight;

  }   

  Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
  Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
  return newImage;
}
```

I hope this helps. I didn't test it, but I've rewritten my VB code, so allegedly it should be okay...

There's also a ResizeStream method here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1576697.aspx/1 that you might find useful.
If you want to keep image quality, you can use the CompositingQuality and SmoothingMode, etc. variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try it out.

Comment: No problems. I hope it helps. Let me know if you hit a reef. Another thing: this is based on max height, so you might want to check for an else if (maxWidth != 800) as well and change the newWidth and newHeight accordingly. But the link I included is very handy, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

100% Worked

```
   private static BitmapFrame CreateResizedImage(ImageSource source, int Max_width, int Max_height, int margin)
{
    float scaleHeight = (float)Max_width / (float)source.Height;
    float scaleWidth = (float)Max_height / (float)source.Width;
    float scale = Math.Min(scaleHeight, scaleWidth);

     int width = (int)(source.Width * scale);
     int height = (int)(source.Height * scale);


    var rect = new Rect(margin, margin, width - margin * 2, height - margin * 2);

    var group = new DrawingGroup();
    RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(group, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
    group.Children.Add(new ImageDrawing(source, rect));

    var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (var drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        drawingContext.DrawDrawing(group);

    var resizedImage = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        width, height,         // Resized dimensions
        96, 96,                // Default DPI values
        PixelFormats.Default); // Default pixel format
    resizedImage.Render(drawingVisual);

    return BitmapFrame.Create(resizedImage);
}


//--------Main------------//

  BitmapImage imageSource = (BitmapImage)ImagePreview.Source;
  var NewImage= CreateResizedImage(imageSource , 300, 300, 0);
```